# Matching grass to terrain

Tags: modifiers, particles

How could I match my grass to the terrain instead of being just flat? I'm watching the video by CG Geek and he changes the order of the modifiers but mine just makes the grass go everywhere.

This is mine[image: This is mine]

Here is the file https://mega.nz/#!ep0xCQaa!E2EziQYLgkIpqCqDO6GR1nKE4KOKUUwUEo0ZgLKXra0

Comment: Enable *Use Modifier Stack* in the particle system settings

Comment: That did do it but the grass was all layed down.
Heres my file if you want to try.
[here](https://mega.nz/#!ep0xCQaa!E2EziQYLgkIpqCqDO6GR1nKE4KOKUUwUEo0ZgLKXra0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to enable *Use Modifier Stack* in the particle system settings, so that the particle system uses the final derived mesh instead of the original base mesh.

From this point onwards the Particle System will start read the modifier stack and behave accordingly, so you have to have the stack order in mind.

You have two *Displace* Modifiers in place so i you want the grass to sit on the deformed terrain it can only be emitted after the deformation. Change the modifier order accordingly.

After that check your object scale and apply it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> , non uniform scales often cause issues, otherwise you will get weird results.

[image]

Comment: Yes! We are one step closer, it worked fine except now my grass has changed all to a light green that cant even be seen when rendered, it happened when I moved the modifier. Here's my new file https://goo.gl/C6TaQv. The original look is in the file and the new one.

Comment: I was just wanting to bump this thread

Comment: Well you changed your object scale and settings, have you adjusted particle settings afterwards? Same settings won't work anymore.